# codrops polaroid gallery, unclickable links

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

Apologies as I'm a beginner with code, and maybe this gallery is a bit more advanced than I should have chosen, but I've managed to implement it as seen here [codrops polaroid gallery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/28/scattered-polaroids-gallery/comment-page-4/#comments)

However, both in the example and my own, the back side of polaroids are only clickable in Firefox, in Chrome and Safari the entire back side of the polaroid isn't active, and I'd really like to be able to click the links I've added on the back.

I thought it might be something to do with z-index differences between browsers that I read about, but being a beginner I don't really understand what's happened or how to fix this so that it works in every browser, not just Firefox.

I suppose it's also possible that it's because I'm viewing it on a Mac? Tried adding outrageously big z-indexes and nothing moves so, not sure what's happening with that.

I'd have dismissed it as impossible but it's doing it just fine in Firefox so I'm hoping there's a fix.